# Working with multi-tenancy/multi db in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, redis, multi-tenant, multi-database

I'm working for the first time on a multitenacy application with multidatabase for each tenant made with laravel using the [Tenancy for Laravel Saas - Boilerplate](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) .
Being the first time for me working on such kind of application, I've read the whole well done documentation that they have but unfortunately I'm still really confused about one thing.

I use [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) to check my db records but on table plus, I can only see the Central DB not the tenant's database.

My question is, how can i check all the databases created for each tenant?

The above package is generating for each tenant a db named `tenantid************************`, how can i see what I'm writing into this db??

Hope somebody can help me to clear this doubt.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple databases in table plus, you can open other databases for the current connection. In the UI top bar there is button left to the "sql" button. Alt. go to Connection/Open a database (Shortcut on mac "command + K")